# Trying to create one array of objects both length of array and objects in array are determined by the user

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, user-input

```
Scanner nos = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Above I have a loop that loops through the length of the number of students which is determined by the user's input. From there they are supposed to fill in four different attributes: Firstname, Lastname, age, and id, with these four attributes making one object. 
    System.out.println("Enter Number of students");

```
int z = Integer.parseInt(nos.nextLine());

if (nos.equals("end") | nos.equals("End") | nos.equals("END")) {
  System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Number of Students is " + z);

Student[] Students = new Student[z];
```

The array length is predetermined and from there based on the number of objects and all there attributes, an array is to be printed to display all the objects in the form of the four attributes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {

Students[i] = new Student();

for (int g=0; g<z; g++) {

Students[i] = new Student[] {firstname + "," + lastname + "," + age + "," + id};

System.out.println(Students[i]);
```

I am having trouble with the data types being both string and integers and I cannot find a good way to make an array of both data types. In addition if the user types in end at any point, the code will cease to run. 
    }

Comment: `Students[i] = new Student(firstname, lastname, age, id});` It should look something like this. And if the age and id are numbers in the Student class and if you read them as strings, then you'll have to parse them into integers

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Java, it is not possible to store different data types inside arrays like in Python. What you can do, though, is create instance variables for each characteristic and then make a constructor where you store your user's input for each student object. Like this:

```java
//instance variables
String firstName;
String lastName;
int age;
int id;

//constructor for Student class    
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age, int id) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.id = id;
}
```

I see you had a for loop to store a new student object in each index of your array and then another for loop to store the variables for each student object. You can actually do all of that using one for loop. Inside of your loop you would use your scanner object to retrieve user input for each student's `firstname`, `lastname`, `age`, and `id`. From here, you would assign those variables for every new student object created and store that object inside your students array. I added some print statements to give the user a bit more context to their inputs. You could then use a `System.out.printf()` instead of `System.out.println` to format your output. As for your program stopping when the user inputs "end", since you were making your `z` variable parse as an Integer it expects an integer. You can simply fix that by passing the user's input as a string and THEN parsing the variable as a new int variable after your if statement.

Here is the code for that:

```java
Scanner nos = new Scanner(System.in);

String z = nos.next();

if (z.equals("end") || z.equals("End") || z.equals("END")) {
    System.exit(0);
}

System.out.println("Enter number of students: ");

int studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(z);
System.out.println("Number of Students is " + studentNumber + "\n");

Student[] students = new Student[studentNumber];


for (int i = 0;  i < students.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter student " + (i+1) + "\'s first name:");
    String firstname = nos.next();

    System.out.println("Enter student " + (i+1) + "\'s last name:");
    String lastname = nos.next();

    System.out.println("Enter student " + (i+1) + "\'s age:");
    int age = nos.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter student " + (i+1) + "\'s id:");
    int id = nos.nextInt();

    students[i] = new Student(firstname, lastname, age, id);

    System.out.printf("Student %d: %s, %s, %d, %d\n", i + 1, students[i].firstName, students[i].lastName, students[i].age, students[i].id);
}
```

If you want to then display all of the information inside of your array, you could follow the previous code with this:

```java
System.out.println("\nAll students in array:" );
for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Student %d: %s, %s, %d, %d\n", i + 1, students[i].firstName, students[i].lastName, students[i].age, students[i].id);
}
```